# Is it possible to assign multiple integers into one?

Tags: c++

Let's say that I have

```
int a = 3; 
int b = 4; 
int c = 6;
```

How to do something like :

```
int d = a,b,c;
```

And get that `d = 346;`

I need just the values in the correct sequence to be stored in another integer.

I have tried that: `d = a,b,c`

But it shows:

```
Error: 'int b': redefinition and 'int c' : redefinition
```

Comment: how about a*100+b*10+c

Comment: What is the *real* problem you want to solve? *Why* do you want to do something like this?

Comment: As for your error, `int d = a,b,c;` is actually equal to `int d = a; int b; int c;`.

Comment: `a`,`b` and `c` are only single digits? If yes, what Spinkoo suggested, if not use a string, what do you need that for?

Comment: Well I have a date stored like That, just days, months, and years in different ints. And I want to get them all together in one int date.

Comment: @ReinisZīverts Bad idea to store date in an integer like that. How will you tell if `1122019` is `11/02/2019` or `01/12/2019`?

Comment: If the three variables represents a date (year, month and day), it doesn't really make much sense store them combined like you want to. It would make all manipulation of the values much harder. Instead keep them separate, and then when you need to present (e.g. print) them you "combine" them in the format you want.

Comment: @ReinisZīverts This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Please state what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Or, since it's about dates, why not use the standard [`time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) to store the date (with a `00:00` time)? Or as a [`time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thats a problem, but its for school and I have a date format like D/M/YYYY so 1122019 will be 11/2/2019.

Comment: Why cant `1122019` be `1/12/2019`? And I still think this is more of a presentational issue than a storage issue.

Comment: Go back to your teacher and mention the ambiguities present in attempting to format a date like that.  I'm surprised no one in your class is seeing the same issues that we're seeing.

Comment: or `1/1/22019` dont limit yourself when there is no need to ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hmm because if i leave them seperate I can't check if inserted date is let say 31/1/2019. But if I get them as 3112019. I can do something like if(Date == 3112019)

Comment: @ReinisZīverts -- Stop making up rules on your own.  Go back to your teacher and have the rules defined, without ambiguities.

Comment: What about the simple and *clear* and ***unambiguous*** `if (year == 2019 && month == 1 && day == 31)`?

Comment: So it is expected that users enters date like this: `3112019`?

Comment: imho the minimum you should use is a  `struct my_date { int month,day,year; };`, then things like `some_data == my_date{ 31,12,2019}` work like a charm and you dont need to invent obscure new formats

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and now I see, indeed the 1122019 can be 1/12/2019. Ohh.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have tried, and he faild one of my project, just because I did the task in a different way that he wanted.

Comment: Okey Thanks guys. I will try to make something with your suggestions. Will throw out this idea about one huge date int.

Comment: @ReinisZīverts -- You can't fail if you show the teacer, using pencil and paper, that something like `1122019` has two answers, and for him/her to clarify what is correct.  That's why I asked why no one else in the class didn't see something like that example being an issue, and to speak up and have clarify what the rules are.  One thing you must learn -- if something you see is ambiguous or not clear, *make it known so that you get clarification*.

Comment: I might be wrong, but imho its more important to use your brain instead of blindly following your teacher. Later nobody will ask you whether you always did as your teacher told you, but you will run into problems when you use 1122019 to represent a date in any serious code

Comment: @user463035818 You are not wrong. It is better to use brain, but the problem with our school system is, that teachers can do anything they want. And they will just try everything they can to fail you if you do something against their will. But I need the papers.

Comment: Since it is now known that we are talking about 3 integers which represent, `{year, month, day}`, (assuming the Gregorian calendar), here is the algorithm to unambiguously encode these into a single `int`: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil

Answer (score 3):

There are ways, but not as you tried. You could assign each value into its own byte in the new int:

```
int d = a << 16 | b << 8 | c;
std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(6) << d << std::endl; // prints 030406
```

Or use nibbles instead of bytes:

```
int d = a << 8| b << 4 | c;
std::cout << std::hex << d << std::endl; // prints 346
```

If you want to combine single decimal digits, you can do:

```
int d = a * 100 + b * 10 + c;
std::cout << d << std::endl; // prints 346
```

In the end, you need to specify more precisely *how* you want these values to be combined (inducing how you can separate them again, too...).

You need to specify, too, how you want to handle values that do not fit into the target (e. g. `a = b = c = 1 << 16;`) – and if you only declare such values as illegal; in other words: you would specify the valid ranges for a, b and c. By the way: if these ranges are non-negative, consider using `unsigned int` instead.

**Edit in response to comments**:

As you are trying to combine date values (day, month, year): It is much easier to group them together in a struct:

```
struct Date
{
    uint16_t year;   // maybe int16_t instead, if you want to represent years BC, too
    uint8_t  month;
    uint8_t  day;
};
```

32-bit `int` provided, this struct won't be any smaller either – and a 16-bit `int` won't be able to hold a complete date anyway (unless you drop some information)...

Comment: Your date solution only supports up to 65535 AD, which may not be enough ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Truth... Might use a bitfield based on `uint32_t` then to shift some bits from month and day to year, could then use 23 bits for, covering 8mio years. With multiplicative approach (*12*31 and zero based), I could get up to 11mio years. Would that suffice???

Comment: Hmm I dunno, maybe. Hard to tell. Let's wait and see ^_^

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *'Earth started to form in year 4 499 997 982 BC'* (assuming *exactly* 4500mio years of age)...

Comment: Who says this program and calendar system will only ever be used on Earth?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Haha, too bad I cannot edit my previous comment any more (13 799 997 981)...

Comment: Well if we wait long enough that feature may become available :P

Answer (score 1):

That's a very strange operation to perform on numbers and I fail to see the reason to do it. If you really need it, you should probably use strings instead:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = 6;
std::string result = std::to_string(a) + std::to_string(b) + std::to_string(c);

std::cout << result << "\n";
```

If you need numeric value back you can use [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or equivalent. It will throw an exception if the number doesn't fit in the integer type:

```
int d = std::stoi(result);
```

Comment: A roundtrip through strings is really heavy for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

**Concept That You're Lacking:**

For lvalue (left hand side of assignment initialization in your case) declarations, you can create multiple int variables on a single line:

```
int a, b, c, d;
```

However, for initialization, only one rvalue can correspond to a single int variable:

```
int a = 1, b, c = 5, d;
```

**Response To Your Actual Question:**

I really liked the solution by Aconcagua:
(However on some machines, especially the old ones, ints are guaranteed to be 16 bits, not 32 bits so I modified it the following way to make it more portable)

```
long d = a | b << 8 | c << 16;
```

In this case, considering your long having a 32 bits representation at least, a is represented using first byte (8 bits), b using second, and c using third byte when you pipe them. It's like adding the byte representations to create a new byte representation for a new long.

Comment: _"However ints are guaranteed to be 16 bits, not 32 bits on most machines"_ That hasn't been true for decades.

Comment: I really do use an old unix machine along with my MacBook. I face this problem A LOT .

Comment: You may face it but that doesn't make it the usual case.

Comment: Alright I see the point. I shouldn't have said on most machines so I corrected my response.

Comment: You probably should change that to some machines. Having 16 bit ints is an unusual case.

Comment: Actually, on no machine `int` is guaranteed to be (exactly - as one easily might understand your wording) 16 bits (by the standard). `int` is guaranteed *always* to have *at least* 16 bits (actually: needs to be able to hold values from -32767 to 32767, but with ordinary bits, we need 16 for...), and some machines get along with (especially older ones, but even some modern DSP, too), the vast majority, though, (legally) extended `int` to 32 bit...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `std::stringstream`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a = 3; 
    int b = 4; 
    int c = 6;

    int d;

    std::stringstream str;
    str<<a<<b<<c;
    str>>d;

    std::cout<<"d="<<d<<std::endl;
}
```

#### result:

> d=346

Comment: A roundtrip through strings is really heavy for this operation.